# Dynamic Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple IR for each client. I want to use one pipeline to copy data from client SAP system to Blob.

I have created all the configuration variables like in below code but i am not able to create parameter for Integration Runtime variable.

Is there any JSON syntax where we can make it dynamic.

````
{
    "name": "LS_SAP_TBL",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "type": "SapTable",
        "annotations": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "clientId": "@{linkedService().ClientId}",
            "language": "",
            "sncMode": false,
            "userName": "@{linkedService().userName}",
            "password": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "KAJDSKJDHLSJDFHALKFD",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "@{linkedService().SecretName}"
            },
            "server": "@{linkedService().server}",
            "systemNumber": "@{linkedService().systemNumber}"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "@IntegrationRuntime_Param - Need to pass this dynamically",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "SecretName": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "ClientId": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "userName": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "server": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "systemNumber": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "IntegrationRuntime_Param": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now there in no option to parameterize the Integration Runtime.

You can parameterize the different parameters in a single IR to use it for multiple resources. But different IRs can't be parameterize.

Please refer this similar request on Microsoft Q&A for better understanding.

[Need help on parameterization of Integration Runtime and Azure Key vault Secrets on link service in Azure Data Factory pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/213506/need-help-on-parameterization-of-integration-runti.html)

Comment: the above JSON code is LinkedService code, can we not pass IR reference name with some parameters like others?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I second UtkarshPal's response. I hope we get this option ASAP.

In our case, we do have multiple ADFs (one per project), and each ADF has it's own SHIR.

The only method to reuse linked services with self hosted IR is to give all SHIRs the same name..

P.S. - If we are having multiple SHIRs within a single ADF, then it's not possible to have same name.

Comment: There are already feature requests for this: 1. https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/b9daf2ce-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c 2. https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/8272fd19-6f26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize IR Name but, you can change it dynamically while deploying the DF!

Use Azure Powershell task "Inline Script" mode and replace the text. i.e.
(Get-Content -path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Repo_adf_publish/dfac-nprd-0001/ARMTemplateForFactory.json) -replace '"devIntegrationRuntime"','"prdIntegrationRuntime"' | Set-Content -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Repo_adf_publish/dfac-nprd-0001/ARMTemplateForFactory.json)

(Get-Content -path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Repo_adf_publish/dfac-nprd-0001/ARMTemplateForFactory.json) -replace '''devIntegrationRuntime''','''prdIntegrationRuntime''' | Set-Content -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Repo_adf_publish/dfac-nprd-0001/ARMTemplateForFactory.json)

Here I replaced the text "devIntegrationRuntime" and 'devIntegrationRuntime' with "prdIntegrationRuntime", 'prdIntegrationRuntime' respectively.

You might want to replace different variations like /devIntegrationRuntime' with /prdIntegrationRuntime' etc.